How can I resolve the problem with **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'**
Here's my code
import cv2
import threading
from deepface import DeepFace
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480 )

counter = 0

face_match = False

reference_img = cv2.imread("reference.jpg.lnk")
img = reference_img.copy()

def check_face(frame):
    global face_match
    try:
        if DeepFace.verify(frame,img)['verified']:
            face_match = True
        else:
            face_match= False
    except ValueError:
        face_match= False  

while True:
    ret, frame= cap.read()
    if counter %30 == 0:
            try:
                threading.Thread(target=check_face,args=(frame.copy(),)).start()
            except ValueError:
                pass
    counter += 1          

    if face_match:
        cv2.putText(frame,("AUTHORIZED",(20,450),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255,0),5))
    else:
           cv2.putText(frame,("UNAUTHORIZED",(20,450),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2,(0,255),5))

    cv2.imshow("Face Authetication Cam",frame) 


    key = cv2.waitkey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

The error I'm getting
File "c:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\minor project 2\\main.py", line 14, in \<module\>  
img = reference_img.copy()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'


Should be reference.jpg instead of reference.jpg.lnk

Verify the Image Load: Even if the file exists, it may not be loaded properly by cv2.imread(). Make sure the file can be read by OpenCV. You can check this by printing reference_img after loading it to see if it's None.
Ensure proper error handling. Here an example:
import cv2 
import threading 
from deepface import DeepFace 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640) 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480)

counter = 0

face_match = False

# Load reference image
reference_img = cv2.imread("reference.jpg.lnk")

if reference_img is None:
    print("Error: Unable to load reference image.")
    exit()

def check_face(frame): 
    global face_match 
    try: 
        if DeepFace.verify(frame, reference_img)['verified']: 
            face_match = True 
        else: 
            face_match = False 
    except ValueError: 
        face_match = False

while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    if counter % 30 == 0: 
        try: 
            threading.Thread(target=check_face,args=(frame.copy(),)).start() 
        except ValueError: 
            pass 
    counter += 1

    if face_match: 
        cv2.putText(frame, "AUTHORIZED", (20, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 5) 
    else: 
        cv2.putText(frame, "UNAUTHORIZED", (20, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 5)

    cv2.imshow("Face Authentication Cam", frame) 

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) 
    if key == ord("q"): 
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

